# I can not send email from python (Azure function) (smtp.office365.com/587)

Tags: azure-functions

I try to send email from Azure function. 
I can send email from local PC

```
import datetime
import logging, logging.handlers

import azure.functions as func

smtpHandler = logging.handlers.SMTPHandler(mailhost=('smtp.office365.com', 587),
                              fromaddr='mailsend@company.com',
                              toaddrs=['myemail@company.com'],
                              subject='---- log ------',
                              credentials=("mailsend@company.com", "dfgSD2sd4401ssd"),
                              secure=(), timeout=180)
        smtpHandler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

        logging.basicConfig(
            level=logging.INFO, 
            format="[%(asctime)s] [%(levelname)s]  %(message)s",
            handlers=[smtpHandler]
        )

def main(mytimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    utc_timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(
        tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).isoformat()

    if mytimer.past_due:
        logging.info('The timer is past due!')

    logging.info('Python timer trigger function ran at %s', utc_timestamp)
```

PS: we already have include:spf.protection.outlook.com -all in our DNS records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to use EMAIL functionality as of now on **Azure Web App/Azure Function**  is via an SMTP relay.  A third party service such as **SendGrid** provides these type of services.

In the Azure Web Apps architecture the actual Web Apps sit behind common Front-Ends which are shared by all the sites hosted on that Data Centre.

There is a possibility that one of the site hosted on that datacenter is sending SPAM emails and this could have the IP address to be blacklisted by the MAIL Servers. So the e-mails sent from that address will be rejected or considered as SPAM by mail servers.
 
This limitation exists in case of VM or Cloud Services too. Azure uses a pool of IP Address, and these addresses are reused. That means you could get an IP Address which has already been blacklisted, as someone was sending SPAM from that address before and hence your emails would be rejected or considered as SPAM by mail servers.

**This is a common scenario in Cloud and it is typically recommended to use an external Mail Service provider like SendGrid for messaging.**

**https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sendgrid-dotnet-how-to-send-email**

Comment: I do not want to use a third party service. I pay money for the service and I want to receive the service in full. 
It turns out that Azure service is not able to provide all the requirements without third-party services.